# onclick="location.href='link.html'" is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

trying to figure out how to add onclick="location.href='link.html'". so that when the user clicks on image it will take the user to a url. 
Just not sure how to include this in the code below. Here is my code...

```
<a class="thumbnail even" 
   onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'holiday', 'logo', 'jcpenney']);" 
   onmouseover="changeImgSrc('JCP_FullImage_321x400.png')"
   onmouseout="document.getElementById('partnerHoverImg').src='../images/FPO_FullImage_321x400.png'">
   <img src="../images/JCPenney_logo_150x110.png"/></a>
```

Been looking at this for a minute and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: wrapping the image in a link instead isn't feasible?

Comment: It is a link...why would you not set the href?

Comment: why not to use href of the `<a>`?

Comment: Maybe the OP is afraid that onclick won't run?

Comment: Use the newish analytics.js API which supports callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have it wrapped in a link.  Just set the href:

```
<a href="PUT YOUR LINK HERE" class="thumbnail even" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'holiday', 'logo', 'jcpenney']);" onmouseover="changeImgSrc('JCP_FullImage_321x400.png')" onmouseout="document.getElementById('partnerHoverImg').src='../images/FPO_FullImage_321x400.png'"><img src="../images/JCPenney_logo_150x110.png"/></a>
```

Please separate your UI from your functionality.  It iwll make your code a lot more readable and easier to maintain.  That said, you could stick the link in a data attribute inside the img -  something like this:

```
<img class="RedirectImage" data-url="www.google.com" src="blah.jpg"/>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".RedirectImage").click(function(e){
    document.location.href = $(this).data("url");
});
```

Comment: The upside of this is that you only have one event handler and one command, as opposed to having Onclick and onmouseover events cluttering your page.

Comment: Just use a `data` attribute `document.location.href = $(this).data('url')`, and you don't need an extra hidden field

Comment: Good call - I use that all the time and forgot.  Friday afternoon.  I edited my answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses... sorry bit brain dead and I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should just add an `href="link.html"` to the a tag as others have suggested.

If you can't do that and you can't add another handler with JavaScript, you just need to add another statement within the `onclick` attribute

```
<a class="thumbnail even" 
   onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'holiday', 'logo', 'jcpenney']);
            location.href='link.html'" 
   onmouseover="changeImgSrc('JCP_FullImage_321x400.png')"
   onmouseout="document.getElementById('partnerHoverImg').src = 
               '../images/FPO_FullImage_321x400.png'" 
>
   <img src="../images/JCPenney_logo_150x110.png"/>
</a>
```